# Test class : how to get results with USING SCOPE Mine query

Tags: apex, unit-test, query

In my test class, I call a function which query `Account` object with `USING SCOPE Mine` clause :

**Test class :**

```
@IsTest
public class MyClassTest {
    Account a = new Account(name = 'Test');
    a.BillingCity = 'xxx';
    a.OwnerId = userId; // Only used this line if I create an user and use System.runAs(myUser) at the beginning of test class
    insert a;

    MyClass controller = new MyClass();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.myFunction(a.Id));
}
```

**Class :**

```
public class MyClass {
    public String myFunction(Id i) {
        List<Account> res = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE BillingCity = 'xxx' AND Id = :i USING SCOPE Mine];
        String myId;

        for(Account acc : res) {
            // Test coverage never goes inside this loop because 'res' is empty
            myId = (String)acc.Id;
        }

        return myId;
    }
```

But this query returns no Account !

I try with `System.runas(user) {...}` without success.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I think you might have to share a more complete Minimum Viable Reproduction case to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: I edited my post with the part of code which is never covered.

Comment: Yes but the data creation is a critical component of reproduction in this instance.

Comment: Ok, I simply insert an Account. I edited my post.

Comment: i'm puzzled -- why is the test class using a `USING SCOPE Mine` ? Why not `ownerId = : UserInfo.getUserId()` ?

Comment: It's not the test class which call directly this scope, but it calls a function. I edit again.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the syntax used in your controller:

```
List<Account> res = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account 
                          WHERE BillingCity = 'xxx' AND Id = :i 
                          USING SCOPE Mine];
```

is not correct.  It should be:

```
List<Account> res = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account 
                        USING SCOPE Mine // see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm?search_text=using%20scope
                        WHERE BillingCity = 'xxx' AND Id = :i ];
```

When I tried this in my dev org, the (corrected) SOQL executes just fine, returning the mocked Account.